# `docker-compose up` context not specified

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

When I run my docker-compose.yml file using `docker-compose up`, it outputs:

```
ERROR: The Compose file is invalid because:
Service webserver has neither an image nor a build context specified. At least one must be provided.
```

Before running `docker-compose up` I ran `docker build .` using a Dockerfile that was successful. So far i've only tried quitting, restarting Docker, and using `docker system prune -a` to remove docker images, containers, volumes, and networks.

Here's the Dockerfile:

```
WORKDIR /usr/local/airflow/
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
```

Here's the docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    postgres:
        image: postgres:9.6
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
            - POSTGRES_DB=airflow
        logging:
            options:
                max-size: 10m
                max-file: "3"

    webserver:
        # image: puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.9
        image: puckel/docker-airflow:latest
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - postgres
        environment:
            - LOAD_EX=n
            - EXECUTOR=Local
        logging:
            options:
                max-size: 10m
                max-file: "3"
        volumes:
            - ./dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
            # - ./plugins:/usr/local/airflow/plugins
            - ./plugins/:/usr/local/airflow/plugins
            - ./requirements.txt:/requirements.txt
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        command: webserver
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f /usr/local/airflow/airflow-webserver.pid ]"]
            interval: 30s
            timeout: 30s
            retries: 3

        build:
            args:
                PYTHON_DEPS: "boto3==1.12.41, notebook==6.0.3, numpy==1.18.1, pandas==0.25.3, psycopg2==2.8.4"
                AIRFLOW_DEPS: "aws, postgres"
```

Here's the requirement.txt file:

```
boto3==1.12.41
notebook==6.0.3
numpy==1.18.1
pandas==0.25.3
psycopg2==2.8.4
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the `context` parameter inside `webserver.build`, which should be pointing to the relative path where your `Dockerfile` is:

```
build:
  context: .
  args:
    PYTHON_DEPS: "boto3==1.12.41, notebook==6.0.3, numpy==1.18.1, pandas==0.25.3, psycopg2==2.8.4"
    AIRFLOW_DEPS: "aws, postgres"
```

Reference: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build